# iOS UISwitch Action called twice

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have UISwitch IBAction in my app, which is:

```
- (IBAction)nearMeSwitchAction:(UISwitch *)sender {

        if(nearMeSwitch.isOn)
            [self getLocation];

        [self myMethod];
}

- (void) getLocation
{
  my code...
 [nearMeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

In my `getLocation` method I've used `[nearMeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES]` which calls `nearMeSwitchAction` again when I click on my switch. Therefore `myMethod` gets called twice. I dont want that. I don't want to execute `nearMeSwitchAction` when I turn off my switch from `getLocation`. Is there other way to accomplish this?

Comment: show ur `getLocation`

Comment: call your method [self myMethod]; in else case. Because in both cases Off/On of switch your method getting called.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: you have to execute what you want,  inside the nearMeSwitchAction Method because in both cases this method getting called. So put all the code that you want to execute when switch is on inside the If statement in the nearMeSwitchAction: and in the else case just return.

Comment: I want to call my method in both off/on cases, just don't want it to be called when getLocation triggers it

Comment: Remove this line from [nearMeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES]; from get location, switch state change automatically when we click it

Comment: I have found the answer. Actually I wanted to turn it off again if getting location fails. Below solution works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop `nearMeSwitchAction` to get called when you changed `UISwitch` value, but you can stop your `myMethod` to getting called. Create one `Bool` property like `isFromGetLocation` and if it is `true` don't call the method.

```
- (IBAction)nearMeSwitchAction:(UISwitch *)sender {

        if(nearMeSwitch.isOn)
            [self getLocation];
        if(isFromGetLocation)
           //For next time
           isFromGetLocation = NO;
        else
            [self myMethod];
}

- (void) getLocation
{
    //my code...
    isFromGetLocation = YES;
    [nearMeSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This works! I tried with BOOL too but didn't work. I guess I missed `if(isFromGetLocation)
           //For next time
           isFromGetLocation = NO;` Today is clearly not my day. Thanks!!

Comment: @thewarri0r9 Welcome mate :)